# brew upgrade results in curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404

Tags: curl, homebrew

running `brew upgrade` results in

> ==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404

> Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/curl --disable --cookie /dev/null --globoff --user-agent Homebrew/4.0.13\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 12.6.2\)\ curl/7.79.1 --header Accept-Language:\ en --fail --progress-bar --location --remote-time --output /Users/username/Library/Caches/Homebrew/api/cask.jws.json --compressed --speed-limit 100 --speed-time 5 --progress-bar https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json` exited with 22. Here's the output:
> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404

other operations like `brew list` work perfectly fine

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this issue by rerunning the install -- [found here](https://github.com/Homebrew/install)

```bash
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```